# What is the root object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, global

You may know the [`global` object](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) in Node.js:

> {Object} The global namespace object.
>
> In browsers, the top-level scope
>   is the global scope. That means that in browsers if you're in the
>   global scope var something will define a global variable. In Node this
>   is different. The top-level scope is not the global scope; var
>   something inside a Node module will be local to that module.

Now I stumbled over the `root` object which seems to be documented nowhere.

Though it seems that I can use `root` the same way as `global`:

**test1.js**

```
foo = 'bar'; // foo is defined in the global scope (no var in front of foo)
```

**test2.js**

```
require('./test1.js');
console.log(root.foo);
```

In the shell:

```
$ node test2.js
bar
```

When I inspect `global` and `root` in the shell they look the same. Try:

```
$ node
> global
...
> root
...
```

So it seems that `root` is the same as `global`. But why the redundancy? Why is `root` not documented? Is it deprecated?

Comment: node; `root === global; // true`

Comment: the outcome of `true` just tells us, that both names are referencing the same "object reference".

Comment: @Lego but reference equality is a stronger result than deep equality...

Comment: As you might not know, ECMAscripts objects are somewhat created in a black-hole (some ppl call it HEAP too) to say so. Even if you go like `var myobj = { };`, you will only receive a *reference* to a newly created object in ECMA-space, not the "object itself". Just for clarification.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is exactly the same as `global`.

There are a few undocumented properties like this. They date from early days of node but were left in to maintain backwards-compatibility and there is no pressing need to remove them.

You shouldn't use them in any new code, as they could be removed at any future time.

Comment: Can you find any kind of reference ? Even in source code ?

Comment: So that seems to be a valid answer. +1

Comment: `root` is deprecated since Node.js v6: https://github.com/nodejs/node/wiki/Breaking-changes-between-v5-and-v6?utm_source=nodeweekly&utm_medium=email#globals

Comment: Finally removed in node 14
https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/ec0dd6fa1cfa03b3983419acedb27ef95d297c82