# How to assign the read the root var in JS independently of context (Browser, Node)?

Tags: javascript, scope, javascript-namespaces

I have a function that assigns an object to a custom namespace, without overwritting existing objects in the path, a bit like `mkdir -p`, for example:

```
assignObjectToNamespace(myObj, "com.stackoverflow.questions.root", window)
```

The prototype would is something like:

```
assignObjectToNamespace(object, namespace, target)
```

So you create the `namespace` on `target` and assign the `object` to it. Obviously if `com.stackoverflow` already exists on `target` you don't want to overwrite it/initialize it.

This method will be used mostly in a browser context, so instead of passing `window` as the target I would like the `target` to be optional, and default to the root element.

Somewhere in the implementation I have:

```
if(!target) return
var recursiveElement = target
```

and then `recursiveElement` is going to be assigned to the second object in the namespace, the third and so on and so on, until there's no more `.` separated elements in the namespace.

If I want to change the code to

```
var recursive element = target || root
```

**What should `root` be?**

The reason why we don't default `root` to `window` is to make this library a bit more general and avoid tying it to the browser context. I know it's not a biggie, but instead of just changing the code to adapt it or just giving up and making the third argument mandatory, I wanted to know if there's a quirk out there that I don't know of.

Comment: thank you @Bergi and apologies for the duplication.

Comment: Oh, it's fine, you seem to have not know the technical term "global object". This question will guide other askers that don't either.

Comment: Which led me just a few minutes ago to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578446/what-is-the-root-object-in-node-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When not in the browser context usually the root context is called `global`, so you could use that.

So you could do:

```
var context = typeof window === 'undefined' ? global:window;
```

Or more generically - without referencing `global` or `window`:

```
var customGlobalContext;
(function() { customGlobalContext = this; }).call(null);
```

The latter works because any method executed without a context ( simply `f()` or `f.call(null)` ) will be executed in the global context, and `this` will refer to it.

## Update

While the first approach is still good, the second one might run into problems in `strict mode`.

After @Bergi's comment, I've read [`this`](http://www.2ality.com/2014/05/this.html) interesting article, which explains the in and outs of the `this` keyword.

After it, I'd say, in order to get the `global` context, have this line in the root of the file (so not wrapped in any method/`function`):

```
var customGlobalContext = this;
```

In this case `this` will refer to the global context wherever you are (nodejs/window/etc.)

Comment: I like the first one @Matyas, I'll wait a couple of hours and if this is the best solution, I'll accept it.

Comment: `.call(null)` will only work in sloppy mode, which should be avoided.