# Where does the var User come from in Passport documentation

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am just getting my head round `Passport` in `Node`

```
 passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
   function(username, password, done) {
     User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
       if (err) { return done(err); }
       if (!user) {
         return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
       }
       if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
         return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
       }
       return done(null, user);
     });
   }
 ));
```

This is all great, I understand the logic. However I don't understand where variables `User` from

```
User.findOne({ username:....
```

Is coming from? This isn't set anywhere and baffles me a little.

Comment: Without knowing the library, just pointing out Node.JS has a `global` global object that is treated as the [root](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578446/what-is-the-root-object-in-node-js) object. Some libraries like to break (what's arguably widely accepted as) the module paradigm and convention, adding things like what you're describing to this `global` or `root` object in order to be accessible by all scripts, regardless of whether or not they've `require`d the containing script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is using a [mongoose model](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) (`User`) that was defined elsewhere. Mongoose models have a [findOne function](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne). It's meant to mostly be filler to show how you would use the strategy to lookup info in the db to authenticate the user.

Comment: arghhh... Good lord :) Learning to use Node and things like passport reminds me of using facebook's api when it first came out, or phonegap. In fact, just anything that is poorly documented :)

Comment: yea, the whole assumption of using a specific db or implementation is sort of annoying and you'll find this in many examples. Some do a better job of explaining it though. maybe open up an issue for passport.js to update that to help others avoid the confusion :)

Comment: Ye, i agree. Either way very helpful. Until that time maybe people will find here