# NodeJS global objects: GLOBAL, global and root

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've started using nodejs recently (0.12.0) and I'm surprised by that, there are three global objects: `GLOBAL`, `global` and `root`. What is the reason of that?

Comment: stuff, don't use them

Comment: Deprecated. Don't use them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578446/what-is-the-root-object-in-node-js