# Why does `global.require` return undefined when executed as nodejs script?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I log `global.require` by piping script to node, it is a function, but if I run from within script passed to node, it is undefined...

```
➜  Desktop  cat req.js 
console.log(global.require)
➜  Desktop  cat req.js | node
{ [Function: require]
  resolve: [Function],
  main: undefined,
  extensions: 
   { '.js': [Function],
     '.json': [Function],
     '.node': [Function: dlopen] },
  registerExtension: [Function],
  cache: {} }
➜  Desktop  node req.js 
undefined
➜  Desktop
```

Have I found Schrödinger's variable - or is there a more mundane explanation?

Comment: I just tried with `console.log(require)` and it works. Must be something to do with accessing `root`?

Comment: @Amit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578446/what-is-the-root-object-in-node-js

Comment: Can you reproduce this without `root`? What about `global.require`?

Comment: @Amit it has exact same results with `global`

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the Node code correctly:

When Node starts up, there's a few different execution paths that Node can take. In your case, there are two: reading the script from `stdin`, or reading it from file.

- reading from `stdin` will execute [this code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/78fd43514f1dc5144c71f9dbc2be3f6698da5522/src/node.js#L605-L612), which, as you can see [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/78fd43514f1dc5144c71f9dbc2be3f6698da5522/src/node.js#L609), will define `global.require`;
- reading from a file will follow a different code path (starting [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/18490d3d5af3131751791e501302bc57865337b3/lib/module.js#L438)) that doesn't define `global.require`;

Perhaps in the latter case, `require` is provided by the module context and hence it's not necessary to be added to `global`, but that's just me guessing.

Comment: I took a different path trying to figure this out, and I found your missing piece [here](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require) - `require` does come from the module context.