# gulp throws an error: TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path))

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm using node v6.2.0. I have a simple gulpfile that compiles ts files and copies some libs.

But when i try to copy the libs i keep getting the above mentioned error.

**gulpfile.js:**

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const del = require("del");
const tsc = require("gulp-typescript");
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const tsProject = tsc.createProject("tsconfig.json");
const tslint = require('gulp-tslint');
const config = require('./gulp.config.js');

const $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
    lazy: true
});

// clean the contents of the distribution directory
gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return del(config.dest, { force: true });
});

gulp.task('resources', function() {
    _log('copy - ' + config.assets, $.util.colors.yellow);
    return gulp.src(config.assets, { base: root })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest));
});

/**
 * Copy all required libraries into build directory.
 */
gulp.task("libs", () => {
    _log('copying libs to:' + config.dest + 'lib' ,$.util.colors.yellow);
    return gulp.src([
            'es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
            'rxjs/**',
            'zone.js/dist/**',
            '@angular/**'
        ], { cwd: 'node_modules/**' })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest + 'lib'));
});

/**
 * Compile TypeScript sources and create sourcemaps in build directory.
 */
gulp.task("compile", () => {
    var tsResult = gulp.src(config.root + "**/*.ts")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsc(tsProject));
    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest));
});

gulp.task("default", ['compile', 'resources', 'libs'], () => {
    _log('Building the project ...', $.util.colors.yellow);

});

function _log(msg, color) {
    color = color || $.util.colors.blue;
    $.util.log(color(msg));
}

function _logError(error) {
    _log('**** START OF ERROR ***', $.util.colors.red);
    _log(error, $.util.colors.red);
    _log('**** END OF ERROR ***', $.util.colors.red);

    return error;
}
```

**gulp.config.js**

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var root = './';
    var config = {
        root: root,
        dest: '../dist/dashboard/',
        assets: [
            root + 'assets/**/*.*',
        ]

    };

    return config;
})();
```

**error stack:**

> [14:03:08] Using gulpfile
>   C:\workspace\main\webserver\public\angular-client\dashboard\gulpfile.js
>   [14:03:08] Starting 'compile'... [14:03:08] Starting 'resources'...
>   [14:03:08] copy - ./assets/**/*.* [14:03:08] Starting 'libs'...
>   [14:03:08] copying libs to:../dist/dashboard/lib (node:11076)
>   DeprecationWarning: 'root' is deprecated, use 'global' path.js:7
>       throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));
>       ^
>
> TypeError: Path must be a string. Received {
>   DTRACE_NET_SERVER_CONNECTION: [Function],   DTRACE_NET_STREAM_END:
>   [Function],   DTRACE_HTTP_SERVER_REQUEST: [Function],
>   DTRACE_HTTP_SERVER_RESPONSE: [Function],   DTRACE_HTTP_CLIENT_REQUEST:
>   [Function],   DTRACE_HTTP_CLIENT_RESPONSE: [Function],
>   COUNTER_NET_SERVER_CONNECTION: [Function],
>   COUNTER_NET_SERVER_CONNECTION_CLOSE: [Function],
>   COUNTER_HTTP_SERVER_REQUEST: [Function],
>   COUNTER_HTTP_SERVER_RESPONSE: [Function],
>   COUNTER_HTTP_CLIENT_REQUEST: [Function],
>   COUNTER_HTTP_CLIENT_RESPONSE: [Function],   global: [Circular],
>   process:    process {
>        title: 'gulp',
>        version: 'v6.2.0',
>   ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
return gulp.src(config.assets, { base: root })
```

The variable `root` is not defined in your gulpfile. Node.js interprets this as a reference to the (deprecated) [undocumented alias for `global`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578446/what-is-the-root-object-in-node-js).

You probably want:

```
return gulp.src(config.assets, { base: config.root })
```

Comment: You are right, i don't know how i missed it, thank you.